# Release build for Rcpp package

Tags: r, rcpp, compiler-optimization

I want to make a release build for an R package that uses Rcpp, but when I look at the arguments to `g++`, I see that even though I have a `-O3` flag in my Makevars file, Rcpp is overriding this with a `-O0` flag at the end, for example I'm seeing this as output

g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"/home/dz5937/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/Rcpp/include" -I"/home/dz5937/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/RcppEigen/include"  -O3 -std=c++14 -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-jbaK_j/r-base-3.6.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -UNDEBUG -Wall -pedantic -g **-O0** -c btsatr.cpp -o btsatr.o

How can I make Rcpp do a release build, i.e. higher optimization level than `-O0`?

This is what I have in my Makevars file

```
PKG_CXXFLAGS = -O3 -std=c++14
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That to has come up before but you "can't" short of locally and one-off editing your Makevars for R.

So the short answer (and here I am going to use the path on my Debian / Ubuntu system which has a handy shortcut of `/etc/R` as a softlink into R's own `etc/` directory):

```
edd@rob:~$ grep -- '-g' /etc/R/Makeconf | grep -v "^#"
CFLAGS = -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-8T8CYO/r-base-4.0.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g $(LTO)
CXXFLAGS = -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-8T8CYO/r-base-4.0.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g $(LTO)
CXX11FLAGS = -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-8T8CYO/r-base-4.0.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g $(LTO)
CXX14FLAGS = -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-8T8CYO/r-base-4.0.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g $(LTO)
CXX17FLAGS = -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-8T8CYO/r-base-4.0.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g $(LTO)
CXX20FLAGS = -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-8T8CYO/r-base-4.0.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g $(LTO)
FCFLAGS = -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-8T8CYO/r-base-4.0.3=. -fstack-protector-strong $(LTO_FC)
FFLAGS = -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-8T8CYO/r-base-4.0.3=. -fstack-protector-strong $(LTO_FC)
SAFE_FFLAGS = -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-8T8CYO/r-base-4.0.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -msse2 -mfpmath=sse
TCLTK_LIBS = -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -ltcl8.6 -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -ltk8.6 -lX11 -lXss -lXext
edd@rob:~$
```

This is (in essence) a combination of three sources:

- things that R itself hardwires
- things that the distribution hardwires for `gcc` and friends
- things that package maintainer (me, actually) specifies for the distro

All this sets your `CXXFLAGS` (and same for `CXX11...` `CXX14...` ...).
You can then set

- your user-local values via `~/.R/Makevars`
- your package-local values via `src/Makevars`

The really weird thing is that even after the almost 25 years that we have *no* mechanism to edit and override this and selectively undo.  I think I recall that for `gcc` *et al* the rightmost value wins...

So to sum up, to be "sure" you'd have to edit out the `-O0` value in your machine-local config file.

Comment: Thanks Dirk! And thank you for all of your contributions over the years!